# 15 second delay with ffmpeg when recording from MacBook Pro's onboard microphone

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, microphone

I am facing an issue with `ffmpeg` on my MacBook Pro. When I try to record audio from the onboard microphone using `ffmpeg`, there's a consistent delay of about 15 seconds before it starts recording.

Here's a recording: https://asciinema.org/a/9I7r5KaZw6J6KuUYsws4SWCM5

**Command Used**:

```bash
ffmpeg -v debug -f avfoundation -i ":0" output.wav
```

**Output**:

```
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-v' ... matched as option 'v' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'avfoundation'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument ':0'.
Reading option 'output.wav' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option v (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url :0.
Applying option f (force format) with argument avfoundation.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: :0.
[avfoundation @ 0x126f049c0] audio device 'MacBook Pro Microphone' opened
[avfoundation @ 0x126f049c0] All info found
```

It hangs on `Opening an input file: :0.`, and `[avfoundation @ 0x126f049c0] audio device 'MacBook Pro Microphone' opened` is what seems to be taking the time.

**System Information**:

- MacBook Pro 14-inch, 2021
- macOS version: Ventura 13.4.1
- ffmpeg version: 6.0

**Observations**:

- This delay is consistent every time I run the command.
- I've tested the onboard microphone with other apps (like QuickTime) and it starts recording instantly.
- The problem seems to be unique to ffmpeg or my usage of it.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this delay, or has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!